# Hiding a control in Asp.net using css

Tags: c#, css

i am trying to make the control not visable through the css but still the control is been shown.

i tried doing like this

`html1.Visible = false;`

but this creates an gap in the menu where is been used

```
HtmlAnchor html1 = (HtmlAnchor)holder.FindControl("lblA1");
html1.Attributes.Add("class", "display:none");
```

i want to hide the control and do not want to display the gap there
how can we achive this.
any help on this would be great

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to use `style` instead of `class`:

```
html1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

You may also consider the option of making a CSS style like:

```
.hidden
{
   display:none;
}
```

And then apply it via 'class':

```
html1.Attributes.Add("class", "hidden");
```

Comment: display:none will remove it from html layout i.e. it will not take any place in the layout. If you use visibility:hidden it'll just hide it and it will cover its own space. For details check this out http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqhidden.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more than one property in `style` element in that case use `Style` property instead of `Attributes` property like this example....

```
HtmlAnchor html1 = (HtmlAnchor)Page.FindControl("lblA1");
html1.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach this class to button using above methods
Very helpful when the button is taking the space , which it shouldn't be

```
<style>
 .hideAspButton
  {
   position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
```